# Using "Install Service" action of install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I have a requirement to install tomcat as windows service and start the service during installation.

Initially I have created install.bat & startService.bat files and executing these batch files during installation using "run executable or batch file" action of install4j.

For this I had to keep the batch file in the installation directory.

So I was asked to use "Install Service" & "start service" action of installa4j so that batch file are not required in installation location.

Can any one help me, I have added the batch file below?

```
    @echo off    
    setlocal

    set "DATA_PATH=%~dp0data"   
    set "CATALINA_HOME=%~dp0tomcat"    
    set "CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_BASE%"      
    set "JRE_HOME=%~dp0jre"  
    set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\sampleService.exe"     
    set SERVICE_NAME=sampleService     
    set DISPLAYNAME=sample Service 

    echo Installing the service '%SERVICE_NAME%'           
    echo Using CATALINA_HOME:  "%CATALINA_HOME%"       
    echo Using CATALINA_BASE:  "%CATALINA_HOME%"     
    echo Using JAVA_HOME: "%JAVA_HOME%"     
    echo Using JRE_HOME: "%JRE_HOME%"     

    set "JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll"      
    if exist "%JVM%" goto foundJvm          
    set "JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\client\jvm.dll"        
    if exist "%JVM%" goto foundJvm          
    set JVM=auto           
    :foundJvm         
    echo Using JVM: "%JVM%"         

    set "CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar;
                   %CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"                       
    if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "%CATALINA_BASE%"      
    set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"       
    "%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% ^     
--Description "tomcat 8" ^
--DisplayName "%DISPLAYNAME%" ^
--Install "%EXECUTABLE%" ^
--Startup auto ^
--LogPath "%CATALINA_BASE%\logs" ^
--StdOutput auto ^
--StdError auto ^
--Classpath "%CLASSPATH%" ^
--Jvm "%JVM%" ^
--StartMode jvm ^
--StopMode jvm ^
--StartPath "%CATALINA_HOME%" ^
--StopPath "%CATALINA_HOME%" ^
--StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ^
--StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ^
--StartParams start ^
--StopParams stop ^

--JvmOptions 
"-Dconceptor.datapath=%DATA_PATH%;-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" ^
    --JvmMs 1024 ^
    --JvmMx 2048
    if not errorlevel 1 goto installed
    echo Failed installing '%DISPLAYNAME%' service
    goto end
    :installed
    echo The service '%DISPLAYNAME%' has been installed.

    :end
    cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
    pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a Java class like this:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap("stop");
            }
        });
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap("start");
    }
}
```

and use it as a main class for the service launcher in install4j.